# How to create a vector (SVG) with XML Code?

Tags: vector, icon, svg, xml

I recently saw an icon on the web, a stepper motor image:

[image: stepper motor]

but when I click "View image" it sends me to the page http://www.nemsim.com/ece395blimp/fritzing/parts/svg/core/icon/Stepper_Motor_-_Bipolar__icon.svg, which shows the XML code for creating the image, I suppose.

How can I recompile this code to create a normal SVG out of it? Or what is the deal with this?

Comment: SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) is an image/application format defined by XML-like code structure. As noted in the SVG 1.1 Standards Document (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html) located at w3.org, "SVG is an application of XML and is compatible with the Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 Recommendation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the server on which this image is stored. The server is incorrectly telling your browser that it is sending text, so the browser interprets the file as text.

Simply save the file using the "Save Page" option, and then open it in the browser from your local disk. You can also use an SVG viewer of editor instead of the web browser.